# Remove all <a> tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I scraped one  container which includes urls for example:

```
<a href="url">text</a>
```

I need all  to be removed and only the **text** remain...

```
import urllib2, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "http://mysite.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
anchors = soup.findAll('a')
for anchor in anchors:
  anchor.replaceWithChildren()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with Bleach

[PyPi - Bleach](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach)

```
>>> import bleach

>>> bleach.clean('an <script>evil()</script> example')
u'an &lt;script&gt;evil()&lt;/script&gt; example'

>>> bleach.linkify('an http://example.com url')
u'an <a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">http://example.com</a> url

>>> bleach.delinkify('a <a href="http://ex.mp">link</a>')
u'a link'
```

Comment: not working... It maybe works for one link but It can't find automatically all links in soup and remove them... But its indeed good library

Comment: bleach works on html.  so you'd want to pass that in, not the soup object.  it also works on the entire document of text.  i use it daily and have it production machines where it 'delinks' docs with dozens of links in a single pass.