# Python remove certain elements in source

Tags: python, regex

I have some source where I am trying to remove some tags, I do know that using regular expression for removing tags and such is not advised but figured this would be the easiest route to take.

What I need to do is remove all `img` and `a` tags along with the contents of the `a` tags that are **only** inside a `p` tag but I am unsure how to do this using regular expression.

For example when it comes across:

```
<p><img src="center.jpg"><a href="?center">center</a>TEXT<img src="right.jpg"><a href="?rightspan">right</a> MORE TEXT<img src="another.jpg"></p>
```

The output should be the following where all `a` tags and content and `img` tags are removed.

```
<p>TEXT MORE TEXT</p>
```

The problem is like I stated i'm not sure how to do this, and my regular expression removes **all** of the `a` and `img` tags in the source, not just the ones inside of a `p` tag.

```
re.sub(r'<(img|a).*?>|</a>', '', text)
```

Comment: "but figured this would be the easiest route to take" - well, as you can see it's not that easy. Why not try other routes then? :)

Comment: Here is an easier route to take [Remove all <a> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058284/remove-all-a-tags).

Comment: I'll be the first to say [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and recommend the wonderful tools of [the standard library](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) (or Beautiful Soup).

Comment: Thanks for the all the links and references. I know now not to use regular expression as it is much easier to use a parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regular expression indeed will remove all tags without using some type of assertion. Although you possibly could use regular expression to perform this, I do advise not going this route for many reasons.

You could simply use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) to pass a list of what to remove.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<p><img src="center.jpg"><a href="?center">center</a>TEXT<img src="right.jpg"><a href="?rightspan">right</a> MORE TEXT<img src="another.jpg"></p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for m in soup.findAll(['a', 'img']):
...   if m.parent.name == 'p':
...      m.replaceWith('')

>>> print soup

<p>TEXT MORE TEXT</p>
```

> > **Note**: This will replace all `<a>, </a>` and `<img>` elements (including content) that are inside of a `<p>` element leaving the rest untouched. If you have **BS4**, use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)

Comment: Noticing your good regex and looking for things to learn in some of your old posts... And +1'ing this for an instructive solution that has nothing to do with regex!

Comment: @zx81 Go here [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52067/foo](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52067/foo)